# Проверить размер файла на FTP через CMD

Tags: cmd, ftp

Здравствуйте.
У меня имеется bat файл, в котором запускается коннект с FTP

```
ftp -s:d:\Distrib\Script\FTP\ftpsend_command_onehour.txt -i
```

В txt файле автоответы.

```
open сервер
логин
Пароль
cd /public_html/adm/data/
binary
mput d:\forsync\onehour\*.*
quit
```

Но как оказалось, интернет у меня не очень качественный на месте, и иногда бывает, что в итоге размер файла 0 байт. Можно ли как то проверить размер файла на FTP и перекачать его, если он пустой через эти автоответ?

Answer (score 0):

Надо использовать два скрипта.

1. Переделать скрипт, работающем с ftp-сервером. Перед командой `binary` можно добавить команду - `dir`
   Эта команда выводит файлы в текущем каталоге. указывая их размер.
   После этого делать отсоединение сервера: команда - `quit`
2. Распарсить полученный лог файл, извлекая размер нужного файла.
3. Запустить скрипт на скачивание (*ftpsend_command_onehour.txt*).
   После скачивания провести проверку на соответствующий размер файла (или/и на дату изменения). Если не соответствует, скачать повторно.